# How to display user input value inside label using onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-programming

I wanted to know how to display a value entered inside a textbox into a label by using the onkeyup method.
I am able to display it inside a textbox.
This is what i have done so far:

```
<script>
    function multiply(value){
        var x;
        x= 2*value;
        document.getElementById('out2x').value=x;
    }
</script>

<body>
  <div style="margin:auto; width:300px; background-color:lightblue; padding:5px;">
    <label for="">Input</label>
    <input type="text" name="" onkeyup="multiply(this.value);">
    <br>

    <label for="">Result(x2):</label>
    <input type="text" id="out2x" name="" readonly>

  </div>

</body>
```

I tried to set the id 'out2x' to label but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where do you actually have the `script` in the document? It should be just before the CLOSING `body` tag so that by the time it's reached, all the HTML will have been parsed. If the `script` runs before the HTML is parsed, your `document.getElementById()` statement won't find a matching element.

Also, the `value` of the `input` is always a string. You must convert that to a number in order to do math with it. There are several ways to do this and you need to be prepared for situations where the input incorrectly has a non-numeric value in it, but below, I've converted the `value` by prepending a `+` to it.

A couple of other things....

You are not using the `label` element properly. The `for` attribute must have a value that matches the `id` attribute value of the form element the label is "for" or you can nest the form element within the `label` so that it knows what element it relates to.

Don't use inline JavaScript - separate it into the JavaScript code.

```html
<body>
  <div style="margin:auto; width:300px; background-color:lightblue; padding:5px;">
    <label>Input
      <input type="text">
    </label>
    <br>

    <!-- Not always best to use an input for output. -->
    <span>Result(x2):
      <span id="out2x"></span>
    </span>

  </div>
  
  <!-- Place your script just before the closing body tag
       so that by the time it's reached, all the HTML elements
       will have been parsed. -->
  <script>
    // Do your event handling in JavaScript, not with inline JavaScript
    document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
      // You must convert the input string to a number
      document.getElementById('out2x').textContent = 2* +this.value;
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I put the script just before the closing body tag and did the following: <label id="out2x"></label> but the label value still stays blank.

Comment: @SaishMahale Moving the `script` is only part of what needs to be done. The `input` value must be converted to a number in order for the math to work. As you can see from my code above, it works.

Comment: I tried the changes that you suggested and it is working now, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Your Case, I have a simple Keyup with jQuery like this

```
$('#value').keyup(function (){
    $('#copy-value').val($(this).val());
});
```

**So This Snippet for Example:**

```js
$('#value').keyup(function (){
    $('#copy-value').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div style="margin:auto; width:300px; background-color:lightblue; padding:5px;">
    <label for="">Input</label>
    <input id="value" type="text" name="">
    <br>
    <label for="">Result(x2):</label>
    <input id="copy-value" type="text" name="" readonly>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with JQuery. Also, while you may have provided a working solution, good answers should answer the original question, which you didn't do here. In fact, your solution doesn't address the math portion of the problem or the location of the `script` problem.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thank you guys, I didn't see the tag but I got the point and I was in a hurry to make a snippet for it. Sorry friends, and thanks for reminding.